# How to iterate JSON array in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have tried many solutions but none working. I want to iterate json array in php. Following is my json string:

```
{
    "0":
    {
        "problem_id":"13",
        "onset_date":"2011-02-07",
        "status":"Active",
        "operator":"",
        "problem_name":"Allergic Conjunctivitis (372.05)"
    },
    "1":
    {
        "problem_id":"132512",
        "onset_date":"2017-06-12",
        "status":"Active",
        "operator":"",
        "problem_name":"diabetes macular edema - 10"
    },
    "pbids":
    {
        "0":"13",
        "1":"132512"
    }
}
```

Following is the code to send json string to server:

```
var finalArrayString = JSON.stringify(convertFormDataToJSONArray());
try{
    alert(JSON.parse(finalArrayString));
    alert(true);
}catch(e){
    alert(false);
}
alert(finalArrayString);
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {problems: finalArrayString},
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(returnedData) {
        alert(returnedData);
    },
    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Following is my php code:

```
if ($_POST['problems'] && $_POST['problems'] != "") {
    $problems = $_POST['problems'];
    foreach ($problems as $key) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

But it prints nothing. I have also check if json string is valid using `JSON.parse()`, but it returns true.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($problems)`?

Comment: `$problems = json_decode($_POST['problems'], true);`

Comment: Your "array" doesn't look like an array to me. There are no square brackets in it. http://www.json.org/

Comment: The JSON String you show us is not an array, its an Object with 3 properties

Comment: It seems an object in which there are 3 more objects. How can we iterate through this?

Comment: You don't iterate the 3 objects, you just reference they key you want

Comment: Can you please show here how to do that?

Comment: @VishalSuri Your initial problem was not being able to iterate, dealing with objects is basic PHP which you should read up on, in my answer I gave you a link to PHP docs, at least give it a read before wanting to be spoon fed.

Answer (score 4):

You need to decode the JSON first.

```
if ($_POST['problems'] && $_POST['problems'] != "") {
    $problems = json_decode($_POST['problems']);
    foreach ($problems as $key) {
       var_dump($key); // This should print an object out that is key/val'd
    }
}
```

Docs can be found on [PHP.net](http://php.net/json_decode)

Answer (score -1):

```
$json  = '[{"var1":"9","var2":"16","var3":"16"},{"var1":"8","var2":"15","var3":"15"}]';
```

$array = json_decode( $json, true );
   print_r($array);

Comment: But the array is not static, it depends on number of db records